# Dynamically load table view content in Titanium for Android

Tags: android, titanium, tableview, google-books

I am creating an appliction which uses Google Books API. So whenever I search a book it gives a JSON response and I load those results in my table view. There will be thousands of books results when I search. But I don't want to load everything in my tableview. Whenever I scroll down it only has to load next books.

Can anyone give me a code or rough idea on how to do this in Android using Titanium? I have checked this post: https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/table_view_dynamic_scroll.js But this is for iPhone, I need it for Android as well. Help me out...

Comment: most of it will work for Android too. Just remove the iPhone specific parts (like animations) and it will work

Comment: i removed those iphone animation part..But still it s giving error in tableview current offset...can u provide any link for using it in android?

Comment: sorry, didn't work with it. But add the errors to question, maybe I can help

Comment: Its not an error..in API Doc itself they mentioned  "e.contentOffset.y" is not available for android.so its giving exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924521/how-to-create-a-dynamically-auto-updating-scrolling-table-in-titanium

Comment: Were you ever able to come up with a solution for Android? I'm coming across the same issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After looking around I have implemented following solution for android:

```
tableView.addEventListener('scroll', 
    function(e) {
        if (!e.source.__doneUpdating && e.totalItemCount % e.source.__pageSize === 0) {
            var distance = e.totalItemCount - e.firstVisibleItem;
            if (distance <= e.visibleItemCount) {
                if (!e.source.__updating) {
                    e.source.__updating = true;
                    e.source.fireEvent('beginUpdate', e);
                }
            }
        }
        Ti.API.info('-------------------');
        Ti.API.info( 'e.firstVisibleItem: ' + e.firstVisibleItem);
        Ti.API.info( 'e.totalItemCount: ' + e.totalItemCount);
        Ti.API.info( 'e.visibleItemCount: '+ e.visibleItemCount);
    }
);
```

Where `e.source.__pageSize`, `e.source.__doneUpdating`, and `e.source.__updating` are internal variables that are maintained by the code inserting rows into the tableView.